# Integração entre MailChimp e React Native app

Tags: javascript, firebase, email, react, react-native

Eu sou um iniciante em React Native. Eu estou basicamente tentando realizar a integração entre o meu aplicativo no React Native e MailChimp, o que eu quero fazer é: A partir do momento que o usuário nos fornecer seu email, e enviar o formulário, então um email é acionado para ele através do MailChimp, uso o Firebase para criar minha própria base de e-mail, mas gostaria de automatizar a tarefa de envio por meio do mailchimp. O método usado para salvar e-mails no Firebase é o seguinte:

```
saveEmail() {
var id = firebase.database().ref().child('xxx').push().key;
const valueEmail = this.state.input;
const valueName = this.state.name;

firebase.database().ref('/xxx/' + id).set({
    email: valueEmail,
    name: valueName
});

//here where the post for the mailchimp API will be carried out

this.setState(
    {
        isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible,
        valid: false,
        name: '',
        input: ''

    }
);
```

}

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tudo tranquilo por aqui?
Em meio a algumas pesquisas e pensamentos, tive uma possível ideia para a resolução desse problema, segue abaixo o que eu fiz para realizar a integração entre o MailChimp e o Firebase para uma Aplicação React Native:

Primeiro de tudo, realizei algumas pesquisas, e percebi que a melhor forma de fazer isso seria pelo lado do servidor, visto que já estava usando o Realtime Database do Firebase e então decidi utilizar as Cloud Functions para solucionar esse problema, realizei a criação de uma Cloud Function, que fica verificando o estado do Database, e quando é recebido algum dado, é então disparado um POST para a API do MailChimp, segue abaixo a função criada para isso:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

\\Code suppressed here

exports.onDataAdded = functions.database.ref('/xxx/{id}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.val();
    var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
    var btoa = require('btoa');

    console.log(data.email);
    // POST /lists/{list_id}/members
    // Add a new list member

    var MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = 'Key Here';
    var listId = 'Id Here';
    // NOTE: mailchimp's API uri differs depending on your location. us6 is the east coast. 
    var url = 'https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' + listId + '/members';
    var method = 'POST';
    var headers = {
        'authorization': "Basic " + btoa('randomstring:' + MAILCHIMP_API_KEY),
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    var body = JSON.stringify(
        {
            email_address: data.email,
            status: 'subscribed',
            'language': data.language,
            merge_fields: { FNAME: data.name }
        }
    );

    return fetch(url, {
        method,
        headers,
        body
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => {
            return console.log(resp)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw new Error(error.statusText)
        });
});
```

Com essa função criada no Cloud Functions do Firebase, a partir do momento que for realizado alguma inserção do Realtime Database, é então acionado esse gatilho que dispara essa função.

Agradeço pelas rápidas respostas!!

Answer (score 2):

Segue trecho do código que realiza essa integração a partir de `node.js` e `axios`

```
const axios = require('axios')

const mailchimpOptions = {
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  listId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
}

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  auth: {
    username: 'anystring',
    password: mailchimpOptions.apiKey,
  },
})

function subscribe(req, res) {
  axiosInstance.post(`https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${mailchimpOptions.listId}/members`, {
    email_address: req.body.email_address,
    status: 'subscribed',
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.status === 'subscribed') {
      res.send({
        success: true,
        message: 'Obrigado! Estamos direcionando seu contato para nossos consultores.',
      })
    } else {
      res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Parece que você já está cadastrado. Outros assuntos mande um e-mail para xxxxxxxx',
      })
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    if (err.response.data.title === 'Member exists') {
      res.send(400, {
        success: false,
        message: 'Obrigado pelo interesse! Seu contato já está cadastrado.',
      })
    } else {
      res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Parece que você já está cadastrado. Outros assuntos mande um e-mail para xxxxxxxx',
      })
    }
  })
}

module.exports = subscribe
```

Comment: Muito bom, gostei dessa opção, irei tentar implementar dessa forma, se tudo ocorrer bem, volto aqui e marco como respondida, e posto o meu código!!

Comment: Show @JeffersonBruchado, aguardo seu retorno!